# Consuming ladon web service from asp.net application in .net 4.0 - not working

Tags: .net, service, web

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I need to connect to this web service:

SOAP 1.1 > http://monitor.keepitsimple.it/webservice/db_test/soap11/description

SOAP 1.2 > http://monitor.keepitsimple.it/webservice/db_test/soap/description

from my asp.net (.net 4.0) application written in c#.

This web service has 3 methods:

`check_login()` - that is working fine in my application

`get_corsista()` - that is working fine in my application

`get_corsisti()` - that is not working, and this is the PROBLEM

Calling this method I don't get any error but the result is null.
If I try to test the web service with a SOAP Client (Firefox plugin SOA client) everything works fine...